# Event Sequencing without sorting

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem and at the moment not sure how to solve it without sorting.

Here is the problem

We have a system which generates several events for each transaction and transaction doesn't have any definite starting and end events(They just randomly gets executed). The task is to find top 10 variants which has maximum number of transactions.

Ex:
Let's consider 6 events

1. Wake up in the morning
2. Eat breakfast
3. Go to school
4. Come back home
5. Eat dinner
6. Sleep

Sample data:

```
Transction Id   Event name       TimeStamp
 T1            Come back home      6 PM
 T1            Sleep               11 PM
 T2            Sleep               8 PM
 T2           Eat dinner           6 PM
 T3           Come back home       7 PM
 T3           Sleep                11 PM
 T4            Eat Dinner          6 PM
 T4            Sleep               8 PM  

Variant 1 ->  (Come back home, Sleep) (T1, T3) so total count is 2
Variant 2 ->   ( Eat dinner, Sleep) (T2, T4) so total 2
```

Task is to find top 10 variants with maximum number of transactions

Current implementation:

```
1.Group events by transaction Id
2. Sort events for each transaction (Events for that transaction is sequenced)
3. Now concat event names for that transaction (ex for T1 Come back home, Sleep)
4. Do the same for each transaction. (Results are stored in hash table)
5. Count transactions with the same sequence ( Variants with counts) (Results are stored in hash table)
6. Find top 10 variants with highest transactions.
```

It works well but takes around 65-80 ms for processing 65K records but the ask is to do it within 50 ms. Are there any better algorithms? Can we do this without sorting?

Current solution:

```
Case Id -> Transaction Id

public String findTopVariants(List<EventlogRow> eventlogRows, int limit) throws JsonProcessingException {

        Map<String, List<EventlogRow>> caseIdsEventLogRowsMap = eventlogRows
                .stream().
                peek(this::validateInput)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EventlogRow::getCaseId));

        Map<String, Integer> commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap = getCommaSeparatedEventNamesWithCaseIdCount(caseIdsEventLogRowsMap);

        Map<String, Integer> topEventVariants = getTopEventVariants(limit, commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap);

        EventVariantResponse eventVariantResponse = new EventVariantResponse();

        topEventVariants.forEach((eventNames, caseCount) -> {
                    EventVariant eventVariant = new EventVariant(eventNames, caseCount);
                    eventVariantResponse.getVariants().add(eventVariant);
                }
        );

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(eventVariantResponse);

    }

    private void validateInput(EventlogRow eventlogRow) {
        if (Objects.isNull(eventlogRow.getCaseId()) || Objects.isNull(eventlogRow.getEventName()) || Objects.isNull(eventlogRow.getTimestamp())) {
            throw new RequiredFieldValuesMissingException();
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> getCommaSeparatedEventNamesWithCaseIdCount(Map<String, List<EventlogRow>> caseIdsEventLogRowsMap) {
        Map<String, Integer> commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap = new HashMap<>();

        caseIdsEventLogRowsMap.forEach((CaseId, caseIdEventLogs) -> {
            caseIdEventLogs.sort(Comparator.comparing(EventlogRow::getTimestamp));
            String commaSeparatedEventNames = caseIdEventLogs.stream().distinct().map(EventlogRow::getEventName).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            int count = commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap.getOrDefault(commaSeparatedEventNames, 0);

            commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap.put(commaSeparatedEventNames, ++count);
        });

        return commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap;
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> getTopEventVariants(int limit, Map<String, Integer> commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap) {
        return commaSeparatedEventsNameToCaseIdsCountMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .limit(limit).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your implementation is too slow, but it's not because of the sort.  The algorithm is not awful.  If you post your code, we can probably point out the problem.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have added code.  I have measured runtimes: Grouping by transaction Ids - 15-23 ms, Sort and concat event names - 37-45 ms. Rest all takes less than 10 ms

Comment: Since you're writing in Java, my first guess is that you're just measuring the run time before giving the JIT compiler a chance to fully compile and optimize the code.  Benchmarking in Java is pretty hard.

Comment: Try removing the `distinct()` in `getCommaSeparatedEventNamesWithCaseIdCount`.  It's pretty expensive and it looks like it doesn't do anything.  If you really have fully duplicate events, then you should put the `distinct()` before the initial grouping by id.  Also if you have a lot of counts > 128 then all the boxing and unboxing of integers in that function will be quite expensive.